# select statement in oracle

Tags: oracle, select

I need to select 50 fields from a table. But the 20th field must be divided by 100. If this was not the case, I could simply write select * from table. In this case how could I select without having to write all columns.

It is a good practice to mention all columns explicitly but when I want to have a quick view of the data for a short analysis, I would prefer something like 
select *(1-19 fields)
     , 20th field/100
     , *(21-50 fields)
from table.

Is this possible in oracle?

Comment: If there is any reasonable way you can do the "divide the 20th field by 100" procedure somewhere else, you probably should.

Comment: Do you care about preserving the order of the columns?

Comment: @Bo. No i dont need to preserve the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly wouldn't want to do this in production code where you would want to explicitly list the column names.  And you'd probably want to either put the computation in a function or put the entire query in a view.  But if you're just doing a quick bit of analysis, you can easily enough put the computed column at the beginning (or the end) of the column list with something like this

```
SELECT column20/100 computed_col20, a.*
  FROM table_name a
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the best tools you can have in developing SQL is a decent text editor with a column editing mode. There's an enhancement request in for SQL Developer to provide this, but in the meantime Notepad++ is a decent choice.

For a task like this you can get the column names by DESC of a table or view, add aligned commas using a column-based editor, and modify the one column that you need to.

It's also handy should you need to, for example, apply a count on most columns and add a column name.

The example below took about 45 seconds:

```
select
          OWNER                                                        ,
          count(TABLE_NAME               ) c_TABLE_NAME                ,
          count(TABLESPACE_NAME          ) c_TABLESPACE_NAME           ,
          count(CLUSTER_NAME             ) c_CLUSTER_NAME              ,
          count(IOT_NAME                 ) c_IOT_NAME                  ,
          count(STATUS                   ) c_STATUS                    ,
          count(PCT_FREE                 ) c_PCT_FREE                  ,
          count(PCT_USED                 ) c_PCT_USED                  ,
          count(INI_TRANS                ) c_INI_TRANS                 ,
          count(MAX_TRANS                ) c_MAX_TRANS                 ,
          count(INITIAL_EXTENT           ) c_INITIAL_EXTENT            ,
          count(NEXT_EXTENT              ) c_NEXT_EXTENT               ,
          count(MIN_EXTENTS              ) c_MIN_EXTENTS               ,
          count(MAX_EXTENTS              ) c_MAX_EXTENTS               ,
          count(PCT_INCREASE             ) c_PCT_INCREASE              ,
          count(FREELISTS                ) c_FREELISTS                 ,
          count(FREELIST_GROUPS          ) c_FREELIST_GROUPS           ,
          count(LOGGING                  ) c_LOGGING                   ,
          count(BACKED_UP                ) c_BACKED_UP                 ,
          count(NUM_ROWS                 ) c_NUM_ROWS                  ,
          count(BLOCKS                   ) c_BLOCKS                    ,
          count(EMPTY_BLOCKS             ) c_EMPTY_BLOCKS              ,
          count(AVG_SPACE                ) c_AVG_SPACE                 ,
          count(CHAIN_CNT                ) c_CHAIN_CNT                 ,
          count(AVG_ROW_LEN              ) c_AVG_ROW_LEN               ,
          count(AVG_SPACE_FREELIST_BLOCKS) c_AVG_SPACE_FREELIST_BLOCKS ,
          count(NUM_FREELIST_BLOCKS      ) c_NUM_FREELIST_BLOCKS       ,
          count(DEGREE                   ) c_DEGREE                    ,
          count(INSTANCES                ) c_INSTANCES                 ,
          count(CACHE                    ) c_CACHE                     ,
          count(TABLE_LOCK               ) c_TABLE_LOCK                ,
          count(SAMPLE_SIZE              ) c_SAMPLE_SIZE               ,
          count(LAST_ANALYZED            ) c_LAST_ANALYZED             ,
          count(PARTITIONED              ) c_PARTITIONED               ,
          count(IOT_TYPE                 ) c_IOT_TYPE                  ,
          count(TEMPORARY                ) c_TEMPORARY                 ,
          count(SECONDARY                ) c_SECONDARY                 ,
          count(NESTED                   ) c_NESTED                    ,
          count(BUFFER_POOL              ) c_BUFFER_POOL               ,
          count(ROW_MOVEMENT             ) c_ROW_MOVEMENT              ,
          count(GLOBAL_STATS             ) c_GLOBAL_STATS              ,
          count(USER_STATS               ) c_USER_STATS                ,
          count(DURATION                 ) c_DURATION                  ,
          count(SKIP_CORRUPT             ) c_SKIP_CORRUPT              ,
          count(MONITORING               ) c_MONITORING                ,
          count(CLUSTER_OWNER            ) c_CLUSTER_OWNER             ,
          count(DEPENDENCIES             ) c_DEPENDENCIES              ,
          count(COMPRESSION              ) c_COMPRESSION               ,
          count(DROPPED                  ) c_DROPPED
from     dba_tables
group by owner
```

Answer (score 1):

No, if its too much work to type out all the columns use a tool such as SQLDEVELOPER which will allow you to drag a table into the edit area and will give you the complete select statement.

Also, it's better to explicitly state the column names. If for some reason the table changes and a column is dropped your query will stop working.

Answer (score 1):

The data dictionary is your friend:

```
select column_name || ','
from all_tab_columns
where table_name = 'SOME_TABLE'
and owner = 'SOME_OWNER'
order by column_id;
```

Run that in your IDE and copy/paste results into your code.  Modify as needed of course to suit your output needs.

Don't be lazy, I know its tempting to say select *, but its much better to specify the columns explicitly.  The code above will make this much less painful than writing out each column by hand.

Answer (score 0):

You could just write the name of every column and in the 20th column write "column/20". May seem like a lot of work, but I don't see any other way.